# Cannot modify web content display in Liferay due to reference to virtual host

Tags: liferay, virtualhost, liferay-6, web-content

I have the following configuration:

- Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.1 CE GA2 bundled with Tomcat
- x2 Sites under the same Liferay portal instance:

  **somewebsite.com** (virtual host is specified for website under control panel)

  **mobile.somewebsite.com** (virtual host is specified for website under control panel)

When I login to somewebsite.com as admin user I should be able to edit mobile website pages at the following URL according to Site Pages section and Liferay user guide

http://somewebsite.com/web/mobile

I am really able to access http://mobile.somewebsite.com/home at http://somewebsite.com/web/mobile/home but when I add Web Content Display to the page and click on configure I receive "You do not have the required permissions."

When I took a look at console I had found that it tried to load http://mobile.somewebsite.com/home?p_p_auth=.....

Can you please explain why this happens?? And what is of more important for me - how to fix this?

Administrator should be able to login at http://somewebsite.com/ and modify any site created under Portal control panel.

Looking forward to any suggestion.